# In VS Code, is it possible to view intellisense descriptions while hovering with your mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

The only way I can seem to get a description for intellisense suggestions is by using keyboard arrows to navigate up and down. The first suggestion is highlighted by the keyboard. If I move the highlight up and down using the arrow keys, the description follows. The only way I've been able to view descriptions without the keyboard is by clicking the suggestion, then hovering over the autocompleted code in the editor, viewing the description, deleting it, opening up suggestions, scrolling to another suggestion I want a description for, and repeating the process. This is far from ideal.

My computer cursor is where the arrow is. I'd like to be able to quickly scroll to the bottom and preview descriptions by simply hovering my mouse over them.
Any way to get the desired functionality?
[image: Example Image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you show what you're seeing in the hover info after accepting the suggestion and then spell out for us what you're seeing there in particular that you want to see in the suggestion details? I suspect the answer will be "ask your extension maintainer to make the suggestion details show the same thing as the hover info", but it's hard to tell without more info.

Comment: Hover info and suggestion box info show exactly the same thing. I want to see suggestion box info while hovering over the suggestions with my mouse. "Available" is being auto highlighted because it's the first prompt. I can move the highlight with keyboard arrows and get description. I want to be able to hover my mouse, currently positioned on the green arrow (getRxBufferSize), and see the description of what my mouse is pointing on without having to navigate with keyboard arrows.

Comment: in my quick look through the settings, I didn't see a configuration point for this, and in googling "`github vscode issues show suggestion details on mouse hover`" and similar queries and skimming the search results, I didn't see anything that looked like a request for this. You might consider [raising it as a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md). If you do so, please comment here with a link to it for posterity.