# Preselection of suggestion on mouse click

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I am using VSCode. I want to read the description of the item in suggestion list but [I need to select it with arrows first, because mouse click just places the item in editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLScU.gif) That list could be long so with mouse I can do it easier.

Is there any way to change current selection in suggestion list with mouse? Is it even possible? Maybe I can create an extension, then what should I do to implement such behaviour?

Comment: related (hover instead of click): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76176484/11107541. also related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103696